# How to create a screen that let user to draw a 'sketch' through finger touch?

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am developing an app which will let users to 'draw' on screen via finger touch - so basically users can write, draw shapes - similar to a white board.

How could one achieve such a thing?